# GAS - 500 error when calling google.script.run when library in DEV mode

Tags: google-apps-script, internal-server-error

Very simple js code

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(testOK).testCall('A87J8HRS1');
function testOK(output){ console.log(output)}
```

along with simple GS code

```
function testCall(arg){

  return arg+3;
}
```

Throws a 500 error when attached library is in DEV mode.

[image]

[image: Uncaught NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500]

and

Uncaught NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ntgnFiU.png]

I started to use library today for the very first time so maybe I missed something. Is there something I need to do make it work in DEV mode? Otherwise it will not be possible to develop any easy way.

Comment: When you change from new IDE to old one and reinstall the library and redeploy the Web Apps and test it again, what result will you obtain? Because when I saw your situation for the first time, I'm worry whether new IDE might be the reason of the issue.

Comment: Tanaike, you are 100% right. I did what you suggested and now it works even with new editor. Is there a way how to report to Google?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you want to report it, how about reporting it to the Google issue tracker? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) And, when your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Well, I thought you want to post the answer. All the credits are yours. If you do not want to then I will. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your situation for the first time, I'm worry whether new IDE might be the reason of the issue. So I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Change from new IDE to old one.
2. Reinstall the library.
3. Redeploy the Web Apps.

When my understanding is correct, your situation might change by this flow.

#### Note:

- As other method, when new Google Apps Script project is created again, and under new IDE, copy and paste the script, and install the library and then deploy Web Apps, I thought that this might change from your current situation. But, this is my guess.

Comment: I can confirm that the first approach (using old editor) works. I did not try the second one.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for your additional comment.